# Is it possible to show whitespaces in Markdown code block?

Tags: markdown

I try to create a coding style document in Markdown format.

I want to show the whitespace (or tabulation mark) inside code blocks.

I try this with no result:

````
```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo();
};
```
````

Is there any configuration to display those whitespaces (if possible)?
Thank you

Comment: Which Markdown processor are you using? The original certainly doesn't do anything like this.

Comment: I'm using the one integrated inside VS Code. For now, I just replace the spaces by a a mid point (U+00B7) and generate a html and change the css to have the result I expected.